# Can one relate $g(\nabla_XX,\nabla_YY) = |\nabla_XY|^2$ with some characteristic class?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, characteristic-classes

Let $(M^2,g)$ be a closed surface and let $X,Y\in C^{\infty}(TM)$ such that $[X,Y] = 0$. I am working on a problem where I have to deal with the following term
$$g(\nabla_XX,\nabla_YY) - |\nabla_XY|^2_g.$$

If one thinks about the connection matrix of $\nabla$ this looks a lot like something related to the determinant of this matrix. Is this expression related to some characteristic class? For example, in the case $T^2$ is a torus, should its integral be zero?

Comment: Do you know tensorial properties of this thing? Is it a tensor or differential operator? Of what order if the latter?

I can try to calculate it by myself but it is the first thing to check - if it is a tensor it should be a full contraction of covariant derivatives of curvature.

Comment: I think invariant differential operators also should have some classification. You can look up this paper for the result im citing in the previous comment: F. Prüfer, F. Tricerri & L. Vanhecke, “Curvature invariants, differential operators and local homogeneity"